# Roblox Adding Value doesn't do anything

Tags: lua, simulator, roblox

I am currently making a Roblox game, where you need to mine ores, and you can sell those ores for cash. I already have the datastore set up, and a tool that lets you mine ores.
But for some reason, the selling of ores doesn't work. It doesn't get rid of your ores, and the cash value doesn't go up. Please help!

The script in the sell part:

```
local db = false --debounce

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) --gets the player
    if db == false then
        db = true
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value + player.leaderstats.Ore.Value
        --sets the players cash to the current cash + the ore
        player.leaderstats.Ore.Value = 0
        --sets the ore value to 0
        wait(1)
        db = false
    end
end)
```

Comment: Is this a local script?

Comment: No, it is a normal script.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that after you add the value of the ore to the cash, it just adds 0 because you set the ore value to 0.

Try adding a "wait()" function after the part where it says `player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value + player.leaderstats.Ore.Value`, don't make the wait() statement too high, just a sec or so.

So like this:

````
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) --gets the player
    if db == false then
        db = true
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value + player.leaderstats.Ore.Value
        --sets the players cash to the current cash + the ore
        wait(0.5)
        --add a wait statement so that it gives the player the cash before it sets the value to 0.
        player.leaderstats.Ore.Value = 0
        --sets the ore value to 0
        wait(1)
        db = false
    end
end)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, but it still doesn't work. I also tried debugging with printing the values, and it returned that the ore value is 0, even though I did collect ore.

Image:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJG2k.png)

Code:

```
local db = false --debounce

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) --gets the player
    if db == false then
        db = true
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value + player.leaderstats.Ore.Value
        print("cash: "..player.leaderstats.Cash.Value)
        print("ore: "..player.leaderstats.Ore.Value)
        print("ore+cash: "..player.leaderstats.Ore.Value + player.leaderstats.Ore.Value)
        --sets the players cash to the current cash + the ore
        wait(0.5)
        player.leaderstats.Ore.Value = 0
        --sets the ore value to 0
        wait(1)
        db = false
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't in this script. Your issue is likely in where you add points to Ore, and I would wager that you're doing that in a LocalScript.

The reason why is because LocalScripts only change the world on your client, and Scripts observe the world on the server. So since *your client* thinks it has 5 ore, the server has not been told this and still thinks that you have 0 ore. So when you ask the server to add your ore to your money, the server adds 0 ore.

To fix your issue, you need to make sure that when you increment your `leaderstats.Ore.Value` that is happening in a server Script. If you're not sure how to do that, see [RemoteEvents](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent) on how to communicate between client and server.